# How to import existing vpc to this module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Hello I'm trying to import the existing resources using terraform module  `terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws`

this is my module defintion

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "eks-dev"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  azs             = ["us-east-1b", "us-east-1a"]
  public_subnets = ["10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.1.0/24"]

  enable_nat_gateway = false
  enable_vpn_gateway = false

  tags = {
    Terraform = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

When i run the plan

```
 # module.vpc.module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_vpc" "this" {
      + arn                                  = (known after apply)
      + cidr_block                           = "10.0.0.0/16"
      + default_network_acl_id               = (known after apply)
      + default_route_table_id               = (known after apply)
      + default_security_group_id            = (known after apply)
      + dhcp_options_id                      = (known after apply)
      + enable_dns_hostnames                 = true
      + enable_dns_support                   = true
      + enable_network_address_usage_metrics = (known after apply)
      + id                                   = (known after apply)
      + instance_tenancy                     = "default"
      + ipv6_association_id                  = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block                      = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block_network_border_group = (known after apply)
      + main_route_table_id                  = (known after apply)
      + owner_id                             = (known after apply)
      + tags                                 = {
          + "Environment" = "dev"
          + "Name"        = "eks-dev"
          + "Terraform"   = "true"
        }
      + tags_all                             = {
          + "Environment" = "dev"
          + "Name"        = "eks-dev"
          + "Terraform"   = "true"
        }
    }
```

This shows me enough information on how to import however when I try importing the stuff

```
❯ terraform import module.vpc.aws_vpc.this vpc-0d8bf51e96d3bc819
Error: resource address "module.vpc.aws_vpc.this" does not exist in the configuration.

Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in module.vpc. For example:

resource "aws_vpc" "this" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

same for public subnet

```
❯ terraform import "module.vpc.aws_subnet.public" "subnet-0d958d42eec08c493"

Error: resource address "module.vpc.aws_subnet.public" does not exist in the configuration.

Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in module.vpc. For example:

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

How to resolve this is the syntax is correct ?

based on Marko E commen's this solve the problem

```
❯ terraform import 'module.vpc.module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0]' vpc-0d8bf51e96d3bc819
module.vpc.module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0]: Importing from ID "vpc-0d8bf51e96d3bc819"...
module.vpc.module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0]: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_vpc for import
module.vpc.module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0]: Refreshing state... [id=vpc-0d8bf51e96d3bc819]

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

Comment: Does `terraform import 'module.vpc.module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0]' vpc-0d8bf51e96d3bc819` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it seems you are using nested modules, i.e., modules within modules, it is not enough to use only the command from the question:

```bash
terraform import module.vpc.aws_vpc.this vpc-0d8bf51e96d3bc819
```

As can be seen from the plan output, the module will actually try to create:

```
# module.vpc.module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0] will be created
```

Which also means that for the import to work, you have to use the following command:

```bash
terraform import 'module.vpc.module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0]' vpc-0d8bf51e96d3bc819
```

The same logic should be applied for all the resources that belong to nested modules.